# recommended book for SharePoint 2007 work flow development (a.k.a) customization using Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, workflow-foundation

Hi is there any full book or part of books which talks about the improved and simplified ways of creating / developing/customizing SharePoint 2007 Workflow using Visual Studio 2008 (preferably Team edition)

Answer (score 0):

The copy of SharePoint 2007 Development Unleashed that I have only has examples from **VS 2005**

As an example of what not to get.